# number to md5 equation while selecting from database

Tags: php, mysql, md5

So, here is an example.

- The variable: `$id=5;`
- The query: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE userhash=$id`

`userhash` is `VARCHAR` type and contains an md5 hash for unauthorized users and numbers (id's) for authorized users.

There is some kind of collision or maybe I really don't know something about equations and md5 but query returns result checked from row where `userhash='5c4efba7d5b8de6ce81f3fa2c7fcd4d8'`.

Comment: no idea what you are asking

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: MySQL does its own type-juggling, and you're comparing an into with a varchar, so the varchar is converted to an int for the comparison: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE userhash='$id'` or `SELECT * FROM table WHERE userhash = CAST($id as VARCHAR(32))`.... but what you're doing really isn't sensible

Comment: Why does the query select from database wrong row -that's the question. Clear?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're comparing a number to a string, so basically doing

```
WHERE 5 = 5c4efba7....
```

MySQL will "politely" convert that string to a number as best it can. By its rules, it'll take all digits from the start of the string up to the first NON digit, which means you end up doing

```
WHERE 5 = 5
```

If you want to compare hashes, you should do so as strings:

```
mysql> select '5' = '5ca...', 5 = '5ca...';
+----------------+--------------+
| '5' = '5ca...' | 5 = '5ca...' |
+----------------+--------------+
|              0 |            1 |
+----------------+--------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

Note how the quoted version doesn't match (result = `0`), while the unquoted/integer version DOES match (result = `1`).

You can directly also compare hash-to-hash:

```
WHERE md5(5) = '5ca....'
```

As well, note that the above query produced a warning:

```
mysql> show warnings;
+---------+------+--------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                    |
+---------+------+--------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '5ca...' |
+---------+------+--------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Nice job figuring out what he was asking!  His question makes much more sense after seeing your answer.

Comment: i'm really sorry for my eng. And thanks, Marc

Answer (score 0):

For authorized users, it should be `SELECT * FROM table WHERE userhash='$id'` and for unauthorized users, it is `SELECT * FROM table WHERE userhash=md5($id)`.

Therefore you can do this as follows:

```
$auth = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE userhash='$id'";
$unauth = md5($id);
$unauth = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE userhash='$unauth'";

if(!empty(mysql_query($auth)) || ($q = mysql_query($auth))){
    //user is authorized and $q has selected row(s)
}else if(!empty(mysql_query($unauth)) || ($q = mysql_query($unauth))){
    ////user is unauthorized and $q has selected row(s)
}else{
    //there was an error with selecting
}
```